# combine two queries of elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a "date_created_tranx" and "phone_number_cust" fields. Few entries of date_created_tranx are null . I want to have particular phone_number within date_range and with null value.

```
a = {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "date_created_tranx": {
                            "gte": "2019-12-01",
                            "lte": "2020-05-07"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "regexp": {
                        "phone_number_cust": ".*702625.*"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
 }


b  = {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "regexp": {
                    "phone_number_cust": ".*702625.*"
                }
            }],
            "must_not": [{
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "date_created_tranx"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

How to combine these ??
I cannot call it twice because The result is paginated 
I am totally new to elastic search . Any leads will be helpful.
I tried

```
doc2 =   { 
    "query" :{
        "bool" : {
            "must":[
                a,
                b
            ]
        }
    }

}

It throws
Error:  RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'no [query] registered for [query]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you're looking for is this one, i.e.:

We have a constraint on the phone number and we also check that either the `date_created_tranx` is within bounds or does not exist (i.e. is null).

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date_created_tranx": {
              "gte": "2019-12-01",
              "lte": "2020-05-07"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "date_created_tranx"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "phone_number_cust": ".*702625.*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```